# Detect logout event inside iframe in phonegap

Tags: cordova, iframe

Any idea on how to do this? Basically, I have a session running in a website embed in an iframe and even though the session and website runs just fine I would need a way to detect that the user logged out (inside the iframe) in the app (outside). Any idea on how to do this? I have control on the value returned by the function, so I can do this something like this server side

```
return/echo "user_logged_out";
```

but i would have to find a way to send this to the app and not only exit the user inside the iframe, if that makes any sense. Any idea on how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can think real application and iframe like parent and child. Here we can call iframe as child. What you should do is, communication between child and parent. So if user logged out from iframe, you should send a message to its parent and then you should get the message from parent to proceed. Below is the one approach for this action:

**Iframe side:**

**1-**
`parent.postMessage('This message coming from iframe, user loged out', "*");` // Here *parent* is global javascript object, First argument of function is your message, second is the target url which will receive the message. Currently it is generic(*).

**2-**(Optional)
`window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);` // which calls the receiveMessage() function if there is any receiced message in iframe.


**3-** (Optional)Below function will be called if any message is received to iframe. In your case, it will not be called. You want to received message from parent side. Here you can also send data inside your message.

```
function receiveMessage(event) {
        var receivedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('received');
    }
```

**Parent side:**

 It is also working in the same logic.

**1-** receiveMessage() function will be called when parent received message.

```
                window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

**2-**

```
function receiveMessage(event) {
                console.log(event.data);
            }
```

**3-** (Optional) Below is the way to send message from parent to iframe. Assume that your iframe has id '#iframe':

```
                var child = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow;
                child.postMessage('Message parent to iframe', '*');
```

**Final note:** If you want to pass other kind of data like object or array, please use JSON.stringify() and send it, after receiving message message use JSON.parse() to get your real data.